# Photos stopped uploading to iCloud. What can I do?

Tags: icloud, photos.app, photos

After updating to OS X 10.10.3, I opened Photos.app and imported my iPhoto library. Around ~3,000 photos were uploaded to iCloud, but the upload process stopped before the remaining 7,200 photos were uploaded. I can't figure out how to get the rest of the library up into iCloud. The screen capture below shows is from the Photos app. It has displayed the "Uploading 7,200 Items" for days now.

[image: Screen capture from Photos]

I've tried to pause and resume the upload in preferences but all I see is Uploading 7,200 Items there too.

[image: iCloud preferences for Photos]

Before I began this process I upgraded my iCloud storage plan to 200GB. I still have > 180GB of space remaining, so there is plenty of room for my photos.

[image]

Just to confirm, I'm on the latest release of OS X.

[image]

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you positive you are on the latest OS X and Photos version? A recent fix was supposed to fix problems of this nature.

Comment: Yes. I installed the supplemental update when it was released. Thanks.

Comment: Try turning it off, then restarting the process. To avoid it from happening again, go to preferences|Energy Saver|max out the time and tell the Hard Disk not to sleep.

Comment: Turned it off, restarted Mac, turned it back on and still the same, Uploading 7,200 items. Nothing is uploading tough.

Comment: I can't answer the question because I don't have enough reputations so I'll try to post it as a comment. You can diagnose the problem with Activity Monitor. Open the Network tab and find a process named "cloudd". Then click the "Inspect" button on the toolbar. Then, click "Open Files and Ports". Then, find something like "/Users/<your name>/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/Engine/filecache/AUJ/cplAUJKxEFVO+Uc1tSp+H24zo0pJkv7.mp4", this is the file that is being uploaded. In my case, it's a 4GB mp4. After I delete it, the upload resumed.

Comment: BTW, you should delete the file in Photos app, not with Finder. There're other copies of the same file in Photos Library.photslibrary/Masters folder. After delete in Photos, click File menu, Show recently deleted, then delete it there too. Of course, you need to backup the file if you still want it.

Comment: Also, the files that are currently being uploaded is under ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/Engine/filecache folder. You can list all the files and their size by running following commands in Terminal, 1: "cd ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/private/com.apple.cloudphotosd/CloudSync.noindex/Engine/filecache", 2: "find . -type f -exec ls -lh {} \;" To find all files that are larger than 500M, you can use "find . -size +500M -exec ls -lh {} \;"

Comment: The name of the file you find with Activity Monitor is some random text. To find the corresponding file in Photos, you also need to use the Terminal. First, run "ls -i <the file name>" to find the inode number of that file.  Then, "cd Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters" , then, "find . -inum <paste inode number here> -print". Then, you can know the date time of the picture by it's folder name, something like "2015/01/15/". That's all, hope it helps!

Comment: @zhengyue - thanks for the help. I tried what you wrote and my Photos app is still not uploading to iCloud. It's not downloading from iCloud anymore either. My iPhone works fine with iCloud Photos, just not my Mac. I updated iTunes to 12.1.2 and even deleted all my videos from Photos (after backing them up) and still Photos is hung. This is very frustrating.

Comment: @tlatkovich - I was also frustrated by iCloud. One of my iCloud account won't upload anything, so I used mitmproxy to sniff the HTTP requests and found that iCloud is trying to upload my photos to synaptic.att.com, which is blocked in China. So I end up registered another iCloud account and this time it upload to some servers at windows.com, which is accessible to me. My theory is that Apple will assign the nearest cloud server to your account based on your location when you first registered the service. Since I use VPN all the time, Apple might think I was living in another country...

Comment: So, to my knowledge, there're 2 situations that iCloud Photos won't upload. One, you have been assigned a server that is not accessible to you. Two, it will take days to upload a huge file. During that time, it appears that the uploading process is stopped.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but my iCloud Photos apps (on my Mac, at iCloud.com and on my devices) are now in sync. Circumstantial evidence points to exporting and then deleting my videos from Photos on my Mac and deleting them from my devices as the reason the rest of my photos sync'd.

Comment: The one key part for me was the Photos -> File -> Show Recently Deleted.  I had deleted the mp4 and mov files but they were still magically appearing from somewhere.  It was from the "trash".  Thank you to zhengyue.

Comment: One thing that it might be is that it just took a long time to upload a video. Maybe leave it over night?

Answer (score 5):

## The surest way to resolve this is to create a fresh **Photos Library** by following these steps:

1. <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> out of **Photos**.
2. Go into  → System Preferences → iCloud → Photos Options… and *uncheck* **iCloud Photo Library**.
   [image: iCloud Photos Options]
3. Reboot if you want to be safe, though it shouldn’t be necessary.
4. Launch **Photos** with <kbd>⌥ opt</kbd>-click.
5. Click **Create New…** and name your new **Photos Library**.
   [image: Create New Photos Library]
6. Go into Photos → Preferences → General and click **Use as System Photo Library**.
   [image: Use as System Photo Library]
7. Go into Photos → Preferences → iCloud and *check* **iCloud Photo Library**.
8. Wait for your photos to be redownloaded from iCloud.

## If you’d rather try to keep your existing **Photos Library**, follow these steps instead:

1. <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> out of **Photos**.
2. Create a backup of your **Photos Library.photoslibrary** file.
3. Launch **Photos** with <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>-<kbd>⌥ opt</kbd>-click.
4. Click **Repair**.
   [image: Repair Photos Library dialogue box]
5. Wait for macOS to repair your **Photos Library**. A full sync should take place once the repair has completed.

[Some screenshots](http://osxdaily.com/2015/04/13/make-new-photo-library-photos-mac-os-x) courtesy of [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/04/13/make-new-photo-library-photos-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same symptoms (macOS 10.12.6, Photos 2.0).

When I opened the **Activity Monitor** app, I found that **Photos Agent** was shown in red and as "**not responding**".

I did force-quit Photos Agent, and a second later the upload finally started making progress.

Answer (score 0):

As with many iCloud issues, try completely signing out of iCloud, restarting, then signing back in and turning on iCloud Photo Library.

Answer (score 0):

Photos for Mac seems to perform some kind of bandwidth test before uploading. I was stuck at:

> Uploading 130 items

for hours while at my in-laws' place with an older DSL connection. No upload progress. Laptop plugged in, Photos in foreground and then background, restarted, all photo analysis daemons restarted, etc.

When I brought the MacBook home to my much better internet connection, progress started almost immediately and all items were quickly uploaded.