# iCloud Photos stopped uploading on Windows

Tags: icloud, photos

iCloud Photos for Windows has uploaded more than 25K items, but is now stuck on about 7K items for almost 4 weeks.

I tried disabling and re-enabling Photos sync, restarted, deleted the settings of the sync process and re-entered it... nothing helps.

How can I tell what is making it "hang" for so long? I saw a post from 3 years ago ([Photos stopped uploading to iCloud. What can I do?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181979/photos-stopped-uploading-to-icloud-what-can-i-do)) that shows a way to display the file causing the issue - but it's on Mac.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you add a link to the post you mentioned?

Comment: Also, how much free space is there on your iCloud storage?

Comment: Have the biggest subscription (1/2TB).
Link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181979/photos-stopped-uploading-to-icloud-what-can-i-do

Comment: I've edited the link into the question for you (something you actually can do yourself on AD). And I assume that not the full 500 GB are already used, right?